# Django Splitting models from models.py file

Tags: python, django

I am trying to separate all the models from `models.py` file.What I am doing is mentioned in this [link](http://www.nomadjourney.com/2009/11/splitting-up-django-models/). But Problem is My one model is `django.contrib.auth.user` and I am wring one function in models.py as follows to generate token.

```
def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):  
    if created:  
        UserProfile.objects.create(user=instance)  

post_save.connect(create_user_profile, sender=User)
```

So how do I import that thing in `_init_.py` file as we are importing model as

```
from myapp.models.foo import Foo
```

Comment: Question is, why would you want to do this ? You just need to connect post_save signals to a model. You would not do anything else with it

Comment: Ya eaxctly If I am splitting model where should I write that code for post_save?

Comment: Oh. I normally create a file called signals.py and put it there. Or I have seen people put signals in their corresponding models file to keep it moular

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should only have either `models.py` or `models/__init__.py`, and it seem like you have both. One of these modules will probably shadow the other, so don't have both (i.e. get rid of the `models.py`)

Comment: Ya I am getting rid of outer models.py file.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm following your question correctly, you don't need to import `User` into `__init__.py`. You just need to import it in the file in which you declare `create_user_profile`. The import itself is standard:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
```

Comment: Ya but where should I declare create_user_profile . In which model file or any other random file?

Comment: @Pawan - it doesn't really matter, but I'd put it in the same file you declare the `UserProfile` class in

Answer (score 0):

You can't import a command, but for example importing the function defined above it, ensures running the connect call. Function calls in the body of the models.py file are also executed of the same raeson (i.e. models are imported).

```
# p.py: 
print "hello"   # a command executed while importing anything
def x():        # a definition that can be imported
    pass

# python shell
>>> from p import x
hello
>>>
```